# How to generate the filter bank for a wavelet adapted to a pattern?

Tags: python, wavelet, pattern

Some textbooks like Daubechies (1991) and Strang & Nguyen (1996) give algorithms to construct wavelets with specific properties. But, I am trying to construct a filter bank for a wavelet that is as close as possible to a given pattern (vector). Seems like this approach is called matched wavelets.

Do you know if there is some code available for that?

Comment: Can you provide an example pattern? Have you considered correlation?

Comment: Pattern here means a vector that have the shape of the pattern I am trying to detect. Thanks

Comment: Have you considered correlation? Can you post an example pattern you are using?

Comment: For example, I have the triangular pattern (0,...,0,1,0,...,0) and I want to detect in **some scale or position** of this pattern in a 1-D signal

Comment: Have you considered correlation and know what I am referring to when I say that?

Comment: Can you give some ideas about it? Thanks

Comment: sure - Post your actual vector of interest and I will demonstrate; in the meantime lookup and get familiar with the cross-correlation function